# Convert multidimensional array into single dimensional using values from child arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following PHP/MYSQL query:

```
$sql = SELECT type, count(*) AS total FROM stats GROUP BY type
$this->sql = $sql;

function numObjects() {

        $stats = $this->conn->query($this->sql);
        while($stat_type = $stats->fetch_assoc()){
            $category[] = $stat_type;
        }
        return $category;
    }
```

It's a simple query, but I just can't figure out how to retrieve the data the way I want since it is returning a multidimensional array.

```
array(2) { 
  [0]=> array(2) { 
    ["type"]=> string(4) "page" 
    ["total"]=> string(1) "1" 
   } 
  [1]=> array(2) { 
    ["type"]=> string(8) "category" 
    ["total"]=> string(1) "1" 
   } 
}
```

What I'm looking to do is convert the values from each array, into key => value pairs. Like this:

```
["page"]=> "1"
["category"]=> "1"
```

I've been able to convert it into a single dimensional array, but not in the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($old_array as $elem) {
    $new_array[$elem["type"]] = $elem["total"];
}

var_dump($new_array); //for print the array
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP >= 5.5, I give you the [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function

```
$reformatted = array_column(
    $category,
    'total',
    'type'
);
```

Comment: I'm glad to know about this function. But the problem with it is that the results will be dynamic, so page or category may not always exist.

Comment: I tried it again after your edit. Although it seems it should have worked it still produced a multidimensional array with 2 child arrays. Will be useful in the future though so thanks.